# Calculate high pressure airflow from low pressure readings

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, gas

How does one go about calculating the high-pressure airflow from an oxygen (assume 100%) bottle/supply. I only have low-pressure flow sensors available to me. I have high-pressure air coming from a bottle that is regulated to 220kPa that then goes into a venturi air mixer which expands the high pressure oxygen and mixes it with ambient air. I have flow sensors on the ambient air inlet and on the outlet of the mixer. I can therefore calculate the oxygen flow by subtraction but this is at a low pressure. Can I just use Boyle's law **P1V1=P2V2** to calculate the flow by substituting volume for flow? The outlet flow is 65 l/min and the inlet is 25 l/min. I have attached a diagram of my setup.[image]